# mmap a file vs mmap in malloc

Tags: mmap

I'm kind of confused by `mmap`.

Well, I know that when we `malloc` a big size of memory, we will invoke the function `mmap`, which will allocate an area in memory. In this case, `mmap` just allocate some memory for some process.

However, I've heard that `mmap` is a kind of technique, which allows us to map a file, which is located on the hard drive, to the memory so that we can have a better performance comparing with normal IO (read & write).

For me, the two things above are totally two independent stories: one is about allocation of memory, the other is about reading and writing files with a better way.

But why are both of them called `mmap`? Is it just a coincidence or they are actually the same technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mmap` provides a way to [map pages of memory](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html). [In Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (among others), those pages of memory can have different backing devices: notably, files, and nothing at all (for anonymous mappings, `MAP_ANONYMOUS`), or rather a swap device or file.

While the use cases are completely different, there is a common theme: allocating address space for a process, and defining how pages will be mapped there.

There are other use cases for `mmap`, in particular shared memory.